# Meteor routing: how to extend RouterController?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm reading the book 'Discover meteor' and have a question about pagination(pagination chapter). 
I have a code in my router.js:

```
//router.js
...
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'postsList',
    increment: 4,
    postsLimit: function() {
        return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    findOptions: function() {
        return {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: this.postsLimit()};
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
    },
    posts: function() {
        return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
    },
    data: function() {
        var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
        var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment});
        return {
            posts: this.posts(),
            ready: this.postsSub.ready,
            nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
        };
    }
});
...
Router.route('/:postsLimit?', {
    name: 'postsList'
});
```

And this working fine. My problem description:

I have another route ('/news') and whant to make pagination for this route too. How i should properly extend PostsListController to make it?

Every my post have a tag option, in this case it is a 'news', so i want to see only posts with 'news' tag.
I'm tryed to just copy-paste this controller(PostsListController) and:

```
renamed it;
set another template;
changed:

posts: function() {
            return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
        }
```

to:

```
posts: function() {
            return Posts.find({postType: 'news'}, this.findOptions());
        }
```

It not working, on my /page news i can see only all my news articles and spinner. I'm added:

```
Router.route('/news/:postsLimit?', {
    name: 'newsTemplate',
    controller: NewsTemplateController
});
```

But when i'm goind to /news/1 i'm see all my posts(not only one) and button 'show more'.
I think this copy-paste approach so bad but i have not ideas how to make it working proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue where /news shows all the posts is because your first Route specification is too generic.

```
Router.route('/:postsLimit?', {
    name: 'postsList'
});
```

This route specification will send all requests with one parameter to the `PostsListController`

ie. all of these paths will route to the PostsListsController:

/asdf
/test
**/news**

To fix this, you might want to make the first route more specific:

```
Router.route('/posts/:postsLimit?', {
    name: 'postsList'
});
```

I am not sure why you are getting more than one item when going to /news/1.
Can you post your code for that controller?